# Grab referrer to parent in iFrame (different domain) form hidden field

Tags: javascript, function

I am loading a form in an iFrame using javascript and adding the referrer into URL to pass the parameter to the iFrame (step 1) for populating a hidden field on a form (step 2).

Step 1 works fine and yields something similar to this:

http://www.parentdomain.com/parentpage/?refURL=http://www.somereferringURL.com/someRefpage/

Step 2 (where I am getting stuck)

```js
function gup( grabREF )
{
  grabREF = grabREF.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+grabREF+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
var referrer = gup( 'refURL' );
function start() {
var ref = document.getElementById('my-formfield-id');{
ref.value = referrer;
}
onload = start;       
}
```

This only (still) seems to be yielding the parent as the referrer (http://www.parentdomain.com/parentpage/), and (in fact) seems to be appending the URL string with a closing  tag. The form and the parent reisde in different sub-domains. I am guessing the culprit may lye here:  ref.value = referrer;

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get this to work so I resorted to grabbing only the iframe parent as the referrer and changing the parent page (and embedding the same form in the iframe) to capture the different campaign referr URLs I needed. I can still grab them in one location as I am using the same form, it just would have been nice to have just one parent (landing page) and pass along referrer to the parent.

This code will do that:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var refVAL = getParameterByName('refURL');
    //document.write(refVAL);

    function SetValue()
    {
    document.getElementById('my_hidden_formfield_id').value = refVAL;
    //alert(document.getElementById('my_hidden_formfield_id').value);

}
</script>
```

Thanks for looking.